# Console command for adding an enchantment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a console command for adding a particular enchantment? I could not find one on the UESP or Wikia sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> playerenchantobject       Spawns an object with specified enchantments    Example: playerenchantobject 136D5 109637 109637 would give you imperial armor with two magic resist enchantments.
>
> The Magnitude used for any magic effect is set to your enchanting skill, so 85 enchanting skill = 85% magnitude,85 damage/+85 health/magicka/stamina, 85+1 sec duration(weapons only).
>
> Any effect with an MGEF ID can be added, including special effects normally restricted to NPCs and some perk effects. Perk MGEFs don't show up on equipment or passive effects, but still work. They also use enchanting skill instead of the perks usual value, and stack with the real perk.
>
> Weapons made through the console will always have about 11.5 charges(regardless of enchanting level), and can be recharged. Some effects don't require charges unless grouped with an effect that does require charges. When used on weapons some MGEF are toggled on hit(first hit= on,second hit= off), like improved nighteye.
>
> Enchanted weapons/equipment created with this command cannot be disenchanted, the game will tell you that you already have the effect.
>
> damageactorvalue and modAV will effect the magnitude of enchantments without messing with your level/skill progress.

From [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).

If you want to add an enchantment to your repertoire, use `player.additem refid 1` to spawn a weapon with the desired enchantment, then disenchant it, see the [list of generic magic weapons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Weapons) or [generic magic apparel](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Apparel). You can use `player.additem 0002e4ff 1` to give yourself a filled Grand Soul Gem.

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Apparel#Fortify_Smithing